# iOS simulator is inconsistant to the preview in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I choose 4.7-inch as the default layout in Storyboard to make prototype more easily. 4.7-inch is iPhone 6 according to [this link on Apple website](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/).

[image: Use 4.7-inch size]

In Xcode Preview, it's ok to show the layout.
[image: in Xcode Preview]

But in iPhone 6 simulator, the layout is inconsistent to Preview.

[image: in simulator]

Is it a bug in Xcode's Preview? Thanks.

FYI, Auto Layout and Size Classes are enabled, but I haven't add any constraint yet.

Comment: AutoLayout without constraints... Maybe you should simply add some constraints :)

Comment: @Vinzzz I cannot understand why what I see is not what I get in simulator.

Comment: Well, because XCode preview, and iOS Simulator certainly make use of different source code. And on top of that, behavior might even be different on device !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If constraints are enabled in your storyboard, then add constraints to it to be sure your layout behaves as you expect !